# prove that $\arctan\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{\cos x+\sin x}=\frac{\pi}{4}-x$, where $0<x<\pi$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inverse-function

I tried to solve this

$$\begin{align} \arctan\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{\cos x+\sin x}&=\arctan\frac{1-\tan x}{1+\tan x}\\&=\arctan\frac{\tan\frac{\pi}{4}-\tan x}{1+\tan\frac{\pi}{4}\tan x}\\&=\arctan\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)\\&=\frac{\pi}{4}-x \end{align}$$

But suddenly I realised $x$ can be $\frac{\pi}{2}$ where $\cos x=0$ and I can't divide it by $\cos x$.

and also i am wondering that $\frac{\pi}{4}-x$ is only valid fro $\frac{-\pi}{4}<x<\frac{3\pi}{4}$.

what happen when $\pi>x>\frac{3\pi}{4}$.

Comment: It seems like the easiest thing is to treat $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$ as a separate case and evaluate directly. The original expression is defined there.

Comment: The equality $\arctan \left( \frac{\cos x - \sin x}{\cos x + \sin x} \right) = \frac{\pi}{4}-x$ is clearly true when $x=\frac\pi2$.

Comment: but how to prove $$arctan(\frac{cosx-sinx}{cosx+sinx})=\frac{\pi}{4}-x$$

Comment: to prove this i divide the expression inside arctan by cosx

Comment: i am editing my question to be more understandable

Comment: Given that $\arctan y\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2),$ your closed formula is only true modulo $\pi.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews didn"t understand what you said

Comment: So for $x>3\pi/4,$ the formula is $5\pi/4-x.$

Comment: OP: Other than heeding the comment from @ThomasAndrews, I'm suggesting that you treat two cases, where one is the special case $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$, and then just evaluate the original expression directly—i.e., don't bother dividing by $\cos x$.

Comment: $\arctan(\tan \theta)=\theta$ only for $-\pi/2<\theta<\pi/2.$

Comment: @BrianTung Nice thanks for you suggestion

Comment: i am wondering that $\frac{\pi}{4}-x$ is only valid fro $\frac{-\pi}{4}<x<\frac{3\pi}{4}$.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach. Let $f(x)=\arctan(\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{\cos x+\sin x})$, with $x\in (-\pi/4,3\pi/4)$.
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{\cos x+\sin x}^2}\frac{(\sin x-\cos x)(\cos x +\sin x)+(\sin x-\cos x)(\cos x-\sin x)}{(\cos x+\sin x)^2}$$
It's easy to simplifie that expression and get that $f'(x)=-1$, it implies that $f(x)=C-x$, where $C$ is some constant. To find it we evaluate the function in a point like for example $\pi/2$, where the function is well defined.
$$C-\frac{\pi}{2}=f(\pi/2)=\arctan(\frac{0-1}{0+1})=\arctan(-1)=-\frac{\pi}{4}$$
so $C=\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $f(x)=\frac{\pi}{4}-x$ in the interval where is well defined